# background image scaling. with changing the size accordingly

Tags: css, image, background-image, scaling

Im making a website and i want to have an image in the background. but using it just in
`background-image` makes it so that its glued to the sides of the window and if i would switch to the phone it would be compressed sideways and i dont want that to happen.

I was thinking that it would be good if i would have an image that is making the bigger side of the window its side accordingly. so if the horizontal side is bigger on window, the horizontal side of the image would change into that and the other side would scale accordingly. but its just my idea, and i'm open to better ones. im also bad at coding so please if you,ll be ansvering dont expect that i will understand :P.

P.S. sorry if i had used incorrect grammar, and idk how to use this site, so sorry for bad modyfication of the text and so on.

thats what im using now and its not how i wanted to do it but im trying many things on my own

```
`#bgimg
{
object-fit: fill;
position: absolute;
}
#bg
{
overflow: hidden;
height: 92vh;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}`
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a background image? The use of `object-fit` suggests it could be a foreground image. Please provide a [mcve] including the minimal HTML needed. You can use https://placekitten.com/ or https://placehold.co/ to get a demo image we can see. Make it a [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: i switched it to the img becous im trying to make it work. the suggestion in my question is not connected to what i have now becous as i said im nad at coding and i dont even know if what i want to do is possible, currently im trying to make it work using img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685796063-d2604827f7b3?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1740&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Change the background-image property from url("https://images.unsplash.com....") to url("the-image-you-want.jpg")